# nginx redirect to https except when specific url

Tags: nginx

Hi guys so I have this redirect in my nginx config to ensure all pages use https, however I want to add a condition to stop the redirect if the url matches `$hostname/videos/:some_id`, only if videos is directly after the host as I have other urls such as `$hostname/admin/videos/:some_id` which still need to be https.

How can I do that?

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest way without using if statements is to have two different server blocks. One for HTTP and one for HTTPS.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_host_name;

    location /videos {
        ...
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    server_name your_host_name;
    listen 443 ssl;

    location / {
       ...
    }
}
```